# {LShift}{RShift}:: to change keyboard layout

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to configure my AHK to change the keyboard layout when pressing both LShift and RShift.

I wrote this to test the mapping but it doesn't work.

How can I do it?

```
{LShift}{RShift}::
    Run notepad
    Return
```

Comment: Answer your question and then accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
LShift & RShift::
    Run notepad
    Return
```